# How to do "python_file.py -something" on my python files? Not sure how to word this to find posts that cover it

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a beginner to coding and when using some .exe files you can do things like -h or -i etc. to make specific things happen with the file. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with a python 3.x file? A link to an already answered version of this would be cool or an answer. Thanks :) Or if it isn't possible just say so.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: I’m not sure what that answer has to do with your question, but krishnan is right. You are looking for argparse

Comment: I think the term you are searching for is "command line arguments".